# Determine What Unicode Characters SSIS Won't Handle

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, ssis, ascii

I'm working with a SSIS package that takes data from SQL Server and creates text files to ship to a vendor. Currently the files are being encoded using ANSI 1252 and the Unicode checkbox is not checked on the Flat File Connection Manager.

The package failed when it encountered this symbol: ♥

This led me to believe that if the step attempted to write out any non-ascii character, it would fail. However, it will succesfully handle: "ş" by converting it to a standard "s". For our purposes, this behavior is great, and if it did something similar to the heart symbol, there would be no issue. I'm trying to avoid sending a Unicode file, as the file is already very large and doubling its size is not preferable.

What I'm looking for is the range of unicode characters that SSIS will not automatically convert for me. Then what I'll need to do is a replace on the original SQL statement, to clear out those characters like the ♥.

We started with `REPLACE(NAME, SUBSTRING(NAME, PATINDEX('%[^ -ÿ]%', NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2), 1), '')`, but this will replace the "ş" with a space, which we are attempting to avoid since SSIS handles the "ş" just fine.

Thanks for reading this question!

Comment: What are you doing to change the datatype to ANSI? As far as I know, SSIS doesn't do implicit conversions. Are you converting the data type somewhere between the database data source and the file data source?

Comment: I've got an OLE DB Source querying a table that has nvarchar columns that I'm working with. I'm not using any data conversions tasks, it's virtually a direct OLE DB to Flat File transformation.

Comment: The data flow looks something like a query, some manipulation and then writing to a flat file. The source data is unicode in sql server and it hits the pipeline as wstr (?) Are you explicitly converting to str (1252) in the data flow or are you letting that conversion happen implicitly when it writes to the file?

Comment: The data comes into the Flat File Destination as DT_WSTR, I'm not doing any explicit conversions. Maybe one approach is to attempt to convert it with a DataConversion task and send the records that fail out to a separate Unicode file...

Comment: That's how I would probably approach the problem at first. You can then add in handling of different error conditions as you hit them. I'm surprised that all rows aren't failing because of the data type mismatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting Windows's “best-fit fallback” encoding. Exactly which characters it converts are not officially documented, and the behaviour differs depending on the locale. Many of the replacements are inappropriate in many cases, and there can even be security problems. It is almost always best avoided. [Background](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/19/515047.aspx)

> I'm trying to avoid sending a Unicode file, as the file is already very large and doubling its size is not preferable.

UTF-16LE (what Microsoft tools call “Unicode”) may be twice the size of ASCII, but why not another UTF, most obviously UTF-8?

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that flagging it "Unicode" was using UTF-8 rather than UTF-16LE, thanks for the excellent information.

Comment: Yeah, the unfortunately-widespread use of “Unicode” to mean UTF-16LE in the Windows world is highly misleading.